# Can Incoherent Polarization Beam Combining be Used to Produce Polarized Light?

Tags: optics

I know that different beams can be incoherently combined to produce high power laser sources. But as far as I know these resultant beams are not polarized. But what if you combined several lasers with the same polarization but different wavelengths? Couldn't you produce a polarized laser. And if you could, would there be any reason to do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

There is, as far I know, no reason that you can't achieve to produce a polarized laser if you control the polarization of the individual lasers and use an appropriate grating.

One of the major advantage of incoherent combining is that it doesn't require phase locking or polarition locking of the invidual lasers. So, if you consider controlling the polarization, you may also consider other technics of combining, which allow better beam quality.

You may give a look at this article "High average power spectral beam combining of four fiber amplifiers to 8.2 kW" ( https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/fulltext.cfm?uri=ol-36-16-3118&id=221684 ).

Comment: Now, has what I am proposing ever been done. It seems to me so doable that someone must have already done it, but I have never read anything that confirms this idea

Comment: Google scholar can help you!

In this one the degree of polarization is 98% :
https://www.osapublishing.org/josab/fulltext.cfm?uri=josab-24-8-1716&id=140005

In this one, they also want a high degree of polarization:
https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-54-4-757&id=310726